# VBA, Building if-then when cell value does not equal string

Tags: excel, vba, string, if-statement

I'm moving data from one sheet to another but only when the cell value in a given column is not "In Progress". I've tried a number of ways to do this (InStr, Len, etc.) but I'm struggling to make it work.

```
    For i = 2 To LRow
    If Worksheets("Tracker Export").Cells(i, COL_KSJstatus).Text <> "In Progress" Then
```

i have tried using .value as well in the above code. I have also tried using

```
If StrComp(Worksheets("Tracker Export").Cells(i, COL_KSJstatus).Text, "In Progress", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
```

I'm sure there is a much smarter way to do this, currently this statement is having no impact and all rows of data are being moved no matter if the cell in column in question contains "In Progress" or not.

Comment: Are you sure there is no whitespace or hidden characters? i.e. that the cell value is exactly "In Progress"  Worksheets("Tracker Export").Cells(i, COL_KSJstatus).Value <> "In Progress" should otherwise be ok if referencing correct sheet and cell.

Comment: Do you cell indentation on the text in the COL_KSJstatus column? It will show up in .Text but not in .Value.

Comment: can you recommend any good ways to check there is nothing extra in the cell value? also, does the column needed to be formatted as text rather then general?

Comment: you can use Trim to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace. But you can do checks with Len() to see if string is expected length. Code() to check char of first character etc...